# Python Multiple Variable Declaration

Tags: python, scipy

I am reading a book, in which they write:

```
fp1, residuals, rank, sv, rcond = sp.polyfit(x, y, 1, full=True)
```

It seems `sp.polyfit` method assigns values to each of these variables in some sort of order.

For instance:

```
>>> print("Model parameters: %s" % fp1)
Model parameters: [ 2.59619213 989.02487106]
>>> print(res)
[ 3.17389767e+08]
```

(I don't know where `res` is being defined... but...) Is this Python's way of creating an object?

In other languages, you might do something like this:

```
Foo myFooObject = bar.GenerateFoo();
myFooObject.foo();
myFooObject.bar();
```

The general syntax of python in this way is confusing to me.  Thanks for helping me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with object creation -- it's an example of [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (or more generally sequence)  unpacking in python.

A tuple is a fixed sequence of items, and you can assign one set to another via a command like

```
a, b, c = 1, 'two', 3.0
```

which is the same as

```
a = 1
b = 'two'
c = 3.0
```

(Note that you *can* use this syntax to swap items: `a, b = b,a`.)

So what is happening in your example is that [scipy.poylfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) has a line like

```
return fp, resides, rank, eval, rcondnum
```

and you are assigning your variables to these.

Comment: It seems odd that a method would return multiple variables.  I don't remember seeing this in any other language (C#, VB, Java, PHP).  Is this a Python thing?

Comment: Other languages have to do a bit more work to do the same thing (return a struct, or a class instance, or a hashmap...)

Comment: This takes the place of something that (some) other languages have that python doesn't (or not trivially): you can't change the value of a variable passed to a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's tuple unpacking.

Say you have some tuple:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
```

then you can use that to set three variables with:

```
x, y, z = t  # x becomes 1, y 2, y 3
```

Your function sp.polyfit simply returns a tuple.

Actually it works with any iterable, not just tuples, but doing it with tuples is by far the most common way. Also, the number of elements in the iterables has to be exactly equal to the number of variables.

Comment: Any idea where `print(res)` is being defined?  I am thinking the code says `res` but they meant to say `residuals`?

Comment: I guess so, it's hard for me to tell without even knowing which book it is :-)

Comment: Sorry, it's Building Machine Learning Systems with Python.  I am just trying to understand the code therein.  Thanks, anyway.